# Guidance on how to structure models on a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, redis, models

What are some good ways to structure models and store on a node.js server?

How should I listen or manipulate these models? Are their libs for helping with this type of stuff?

I'm just looking for some general guidance and good approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Model.js
var Model = {
   ...
};

module.exports = Model;
```

Just organize it like you normally would.

Generally models contain domain specific code and are a wrapper around some kind of data store.

A data store should just be a wrapper around a table / database based on your noSQL store of choice.

Comment: What about setter/getter, listening type stuff?

Comment: @fancy it's called inherit/mixin EventEmitter then listen and emit events

Comment: Are there any libs that give you defaults like add/remove and change events that carry the changed attributes, etc?

Comment: I'll give a bit more detail. I'm trying to have a lightweight data model on the server that stays in sync with a backbone model on the client. The server model can be manipulated by the changing client model or processes on the server, same could be said for the client model. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @fancy you can use backbone on the server. To be honest you don't need a library or framework for this. Just write it. If you want really aggressive server-client synchronization done for you look into [racer](https://github.com/codeparty/racer)

Comment: Yea, I'm down for writing it if needed it's not that. I just want to make sure i'm approaching this issue from the correct viewpoint. My plan was to build something where these two models emit the changes to one another. I didn't know if backbone on the server was really a great idea or is I should just build something more lightweight to receive the messages from backbone. I've looked at racer, does it work with backbone? What approach would you recommend? Thanks again for the guidance on this.

Comment: @fancy You can use [derby](https://github.com/codeparty/derby) if you want a full framework. I don't think these things work very well with backbone. As for using backbone on the server, that's more out of code re-use. You still need to write syncrhonization glue